# How to changed hover line width in LineChart rechart

Tags: reactjs, recharts

How to make line width more, which appear when hover active with filled dots in LineChart recharts.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found need just to put cursor props to tooltip:

```
<Tooltip cursor={{ stroke: 'red', strokeWidth: 2 }} />
```

Result:

[image]